# Timers in PyQt based GUI

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I am facing a problem while running the timers simultaneously one by one.The next timer is running and previous one get stopped and after reaching the time the previous one starts. The problematic code is listed below.

```
import time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys


try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)



class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQT tuts!")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('pythonlogo.png'))
        self.home()


    def home(self):

        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pb"))
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.timer)
        self.btn.setText("Timer1")
        self.btn.resize(65,25)
        self.btn.move(100,100)

        self.btn2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pb2"))
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.timer2)
        self.btn2.setText("Timer2")
        self.btn2.resize(65,25)
        self.btn2.move(100,150)

        self.btn3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pb3"))
        self.btn3.clicked.connect(self.timer3)
        self.btn3.setText("Timer3")
        self.btn3.resize(65,25)
        self.btn3.move(100,200)

        self.btn4 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pb4"))
        self.btn4.clicked.connect(self.timer4)
        self.btn4.setText("Timer4")
        self.btn4.resize(65,25)
        self.btn4.move(100,250)


        self.show()


    def timer(self):

        # uin = input("enter the time : ")

        when_to_stop = 10 
        # abs(int(uin))

        while when_to_stop > 0:
            m, s = divmod(when_to_stop, 60)
            h, m = divmod(m, 60)
            time_left = str(h).zfill(2) + ":" + str(m).zfill(2) + ":" + str(s).zfill(2)

            # print(time_left+'\r')
            time.sleep(1.0)
            when_to_stop -= 1
            self.btn.setText(str(time_left))
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()


    def timer2(self):

        # uin = input("enter the time : ")

        when_to_stop = 10 
        # abs(int(uin))

        while when_to_stop > 0:
            m, s = divmod(when_to_stop, 60)
            h, m = divmod(m, 60)
            time_left = str(h).zfill(2) + ":" + str(m).zfill(2) + ":" + str(s).zfill(2)

            # print(time_left+'\r')
            time.sleep(1.0)
            when_to_stop -= 1
            self.btn2.setText(str(time_left))
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()


    def timer3(self):

        # uin = input("enter the time : ")

        when_to_stop = 10
        # abs(int(uin))

        while when_to_stop > 0:
            m, s = divmod(when_to_stop, 60)
            h, m = divmod(m, 60)
            time_left = str(h).zfill(2) + ":" + str(m).zfill(2) + ":" + str(s).zfill(2)

            # print(time_left+'\r')
            time.sleep(1.0)
            when_to_stop -= 1
            self.btn3.setText(str(time_left))
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()



     def timer4(self):

        # uin = input("enter the time : ")

        when_to_stop = 10 
        # abs(int(uin))

        while when_to_stop > 0:
            m, s = divmod(when_to_stop, 60)
            h, m = divmod(m, 60)
            time_left = str(h).zfill(2) + ":" + str(m).zfill(2) + ":" + str(s).zfill(2)

            # print(time_left+'\r')
            time.sleep(1.0)
            when_to_stop -= 1
            self.btn4.setText(str(time_left))
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()




def run():


    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.sleep()` should not be used in the GUI because it will block the GUI eventloop causing problems like not updating the GUI, besides using input (), and consider bad practice calling `processEvents()`.

Qt offers QTimer which is a class specialized in calling a specific task every certain interval of time.

In the next part I show an example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from functools import partial


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(centralwidget)

        for i in range(4):
            button = QtGui.QPushButton("Timer{}".format(i+1))
            layout.addWidget(button)
            button.clicked.connect(partial(self.onClicked, button))

    def onClicked(self, button):
        sec = 10 # seconds
        timer =  button.property("timer").toPyObject()
        if timer is None:
            timer = QtCore.QTimer(button)
        timer.stop()
        timer.setInterval(1000)
        timer.setProperty("button", button)
        timer.setProperty("endTime", QtCore.QTime.currentTime().addMSecs(sec*1000+10))
        timer.timeout.connect(partial(self.onTimeout, timer))
        self.onTimeout(timer)
        timer.start()
        button.setProperty("timer", timer)

    def onTimeout(self, timer):
        button= timer.property("button")
        if hasattr(button, 'toPyObject'):
            button = button.toPyObject()
        tm = timer.property("endTime").toPyObject()
        if hasattr(tm, 'toPyObject'):
            tm = tm.toPyObject()
        ms = QtCore.QTime.currentTime().msecsTo(tm)
        if ms < 0:
            timer.stop()
        else:
            button.setText(QtCore.QTime().addMSecs(ms).toString())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thank you sir for your reply,but  timer is not showing any values on the button

Comment: @amanrawat 
Have you tried my code or have you adapted it to your initial code? Have you pressed the button?

Comment: yes,sir I  adapted your code and press the button but still not showing timers value on the button.

Comment: @amanrawat 
First try my original code, if it works, the problem is in your adaptation, not in my answer. tell me if my example works.

Comment: @amanrawat Well, it works for me correctly, what version of python and pyqt4?

Comment: python 2.7 and pyqt4.11.4

Comment: @amanrawat You have to indicate the version of python, I have already added the necessary compatibility, try it and tell me if I help you, if so do not forget to mark it as correct.

Comment: Thank you sir its working properly know it's my fault.

Comment: Hi sir ,I don't want to use layout because in this i want to add  more buttons in parallel and want to change there size and there color and want to add more labels.I want a specific window of 370x470 .And also want to add more stuff on that.

Comment: @amanrawat  
That's not what he asks, his question is relative to timers, not to positions or geometry. I think you have the ability to modify the code for your personal goal, it is also a good practice for those who start. ;)

Comment: hi sir can you tell me that  how your program knows that which timer is clicked.

Comment: `print(button.text())`

Comment: And how i can enable or disable that button

Comment: Hello sir, I need your help to know that how this timer is working and facing problem while using database to update my  values. I don't understand "timer =  button.property("timer").toPyObject()" us e of it

Comment: Hi sir actually, Inside the timer function I am updating the database values on the basis of input barcode .Suppose if i run the first timer corresponding to its barcode it updates the data properly for it but if i run second timer corresponding tto its barcode it updates the previous timer value with the second timer value barcode but i want the second timer values to be effected.

Comment: These questions should be the subject of further questions, not an extended dialogue in comments. The original question has been answered.